# Why is LoginModule being called every time between web and ejb container?

Tags: java-ee-6, jboss7.x

Immediately after updating an application user's password in the database, I noticed that JBoss throws javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS013323: Invalid User.  This led to the discovery that the LoginModule was being called every time between the web and ejb container.  How can I make this stop?

I'm running AS 7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT and I added cache-type="default" to my configuration after reading about the issue in [jira: AS7-3498](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3498) (thanks @Quincy for the pointer).  However this did not resolve the problem.  My security domain configuration is as follows:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="PatracSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="DatabaseUsers" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/postgresdb"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT userpassword FROM applicationuser WHERE email=?"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT r.name, 'Roles' FROM USER_ROLE ur JOIN APPLICATIONUSER u ON ur.userid=u.id JOIN ROLE r ON ur.roleid=r.id where u.email=?"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
```

Changing the password and persisting the change via SFSB happens without error, but as soon as the application attempts to do some session house keeping, which involves using another SFSB a FailedLoginException is thrown.

Here's the stack trace:

```
00:25:35,521 ERROR [org.jboss.security] (http-/127.0.0.1:8443-2) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:283) [picketbox-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor590.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:408) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.authenticate(SimpleSecurityManager.java:354) [jboss-as-security-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.push(SimpleSecurityManager.java:292) [jboss-as-security-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:49) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:74) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:42) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.patrac.service.LoginHistoryService$$$view94.create(Unknown Source) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.SessionManager.createLoginHistoryRecord(SessionManager.java:163) [classes:]
    at com.patrac.controller.SessionManager.endOfSessionHouseKeeping(SessionManager.java:130) [classes:]
    at com.patrac.controller.SessionManager.logout(SessionManager.java:87) [classes:]
    at com.patrac.controller.SessionManager.changePassword(SessionManager.java:236) [classes:]
    at com.patrac.controller.SessionManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.changePassword(SessionManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at com.patrac.controller.backingbean.ChangePasswordBean.updateUserPasswordInSession(ChangePasswordBean.java:44) [classes:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.effect.ChangePasswordEffect.performAction(ChangePasswordEffect.java:21) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.effect.ChangePasswordEffect.performAction(ChangePasswordEffect.java:10) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.transition.Transition.fire(Transition.java:60) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.transition.GoToWorkflowTransition.fire(GoToWorkflowTransition.java:49) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.workflow.ChangePasswordWorkflow$1.evaluate(ChangePasswordWorkflow.java:62) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.workflow.ChangePasswordWorkflow$1.evaluate(ChangePasswordWorkflow.java:56) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.event.Event.trigger(Event.java:85) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.backingbean.BackingBean.dispatch(BackingBean.java:68) [classes:]
    at com.patrac.controller.backingbean.ChangePasswordBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.dispatch(ChangePasswordBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.9.Final.jar:2012-08-06 19:12]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.9.Final.jar:2012-08-06 19:12]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.9.Final.jar:2012-08-06 19:12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at com.patrac.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:46) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:634) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]


00:25:35,566 ERROR [org.jboss.security] (http-/127.0.0.1:8443-2) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:283) [picketbox-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor590.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:408) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.authenticate(SimpleSecurityManager.java:354) [jboss-as-security-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.push(SimpleSecurityManager.java:292) [jboss-as-security-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:49) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:74) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:42) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentIdInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentIdInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.screen.ChangePasswordScreen$$$view77.findLeafStateAndExitUpward(Unknown Source) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.transition.Transition.exitSource(Transition.java:90) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.transition.Transition.fire(Transition.java:62) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.transition.GoToWorkflowTransition.fire(GoToWorkflowTransition.java:49) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.workflow.ChangePasswordWorkflow$1.evaluate(ChangePasswordWorkflow.java:62) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.workflow.ChangePasswordWorkflow$1.evaluate(ChangePasswordWorkflow.java:56) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.statemachine.event.Event.trigger(Event.java:85) [Patrac-ejb.jar:]
    at com.patrac.controller.backingbean.BackingBean.dispatch(BackingBean.java:68) [classes:]
    at com.patrac.controller.backingbean.ChangePasswordBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.dispatch(ChangePasswordBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.9.Final.jar:2012-08-06 19:12]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.9.Final.jar:2012-08-06 19:12]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.13-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.6.Final.jar:2.0.6.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.9.Final.jar:2012-08-06 19:12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at com.patrac.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:46) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:634) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `SessionManager#logout` (which programmatically logs out the user e.g. `HttpServletRequest#logout`)) was invoked before invoking `LoginHistoryService#create`.  The "Invalid User" error was a result of logout removing the principal prior to the invocation of create on the SLSB.  Invoking `LoginHistoryService#create` before `HttpServletRequest#logout` solved the problem.

I should have caught that!  My fault for looking at code through blurry eyes at 4 AM.

Answer (score 2):

This should be related to the issue.
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3498

Adding `cache-type="default"` to the login module should solve this.

Comment: Would that be `<security-domain name="PatracSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">`?  I didn't see cached=default, but I did see cache-type=default in the examples at https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecurityDomainModel.  I tried using cache-type=default but it did not change the outcome.

Comment: Yes it should be cache type. And you may need to get a newer version of jboss which the bug is fixed.

Comment: I'm using 7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.  I read through https://community.jboss.org/thread/178003, which seems closest to the problem I'm observing but it seems the discussion ended Feb 2012 and AS7-3498 was marked as resolved in March 2012.  And it looks like the fix is in version 7.1.2.

Comment: So, adding cache-type="default" did not resolve the problem although the fix, which, according to Jira, was made in v. 7.1.2 was incorporated in the version I am using (7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT).

Comment: 7.1.2.Final is not a release as it turns out (https://community.jboss.org/thread/197780), so I had to git and build the source.  Unfortunately, it did not resolve the problem.  How should I proceed?  I've never filled out or re-opened a Jira before.  Any suggestions?